# play framework 2.1.5 onHandlerNotFound not work

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

my play framework 2.1.5 encounters a problem when Override the GlobalSettings onHandlerNotFound and onError

```
 public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
        public Result onHandlerNotFound(RequestHeader request){
            return play.mvc.Results.notFound("request" + request.uri());
        }  
        public Result onError(RequestHeader request, Throwable t) {
            return play.mvc.Results.internalServerError(
               "---onError---"
            );
        }  
    }
```

I visit a not exist url, it displays the play original error page but not call onHandlerNotFound method.
[image]

and also, I create an error in my other controller code, e.g.

```
   try {
        temp = null;
        temp.success = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error occurred", e);
    }
```

It displays the original page but did not call the  method onError(RequestHeader request, Throwable t)
[image]

I don't no why , I did what as this ticket said:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaGlobal

Can anyone explains this?

Answer (score 1):

I copied below code from your link, my guess is that you forgot to put `@Override`. Because that tells the app that you want to override the default onHandlerNotFound, same goes for onError.

```
@Override
public Result onHandlerNotFound(RequestHeader request) {
   return Results.notFound(
      views.html.pageNotFound(request.uri())
   );
}
@Override
public Result onError(RequestHeader request, Throwable t) {
  return internalServerError(
     views.html.errorPage(t)
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi but the GlobalSettings is not an abstract class or an interface, how can I override the method? BTW, when I pu the  @Override, the IDE says "The method onError(RequestHeader request, Throwable t) of type Global must override or implement a aupertype method", and I cannot compile the code.

Comment: @user3231931 this worked for me in Play 2.2 but I just upgraded to Play 2.3.8 and it's throwing an error now that I cannot override OnError in GlobalSettings.